# Where in the Matrix trilogy does Smith say dialogue about the "meaning of existence" being "death"?

Tags: the-matrix

I very specifically recall when watching 'The Matrix Revolutions', Agent Smith (in the final fight) said something akin to

> "all the wars, philosophies, ... are to justify the utter
>   meaninglessness of existence and the only meaning of existence is
>   death."

However, I can't find any evidence on the web or in the transcript on the Matrix Wiki with him saying these words. **Is there more than one version?**

Comment: I'm 100% certain that Smith never said this. Are you perhaps thinking of [the scene before the end fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jM8ICPAPgQo&feature=youtu.be&t=38s)? "*The purpose of life is to end*"

Comment: We live in the Matrix, and there's been a glitch: the transcript changed.

Comment: I agree with @Richard that Smith didn't say this. In addition to Richard's suggestion, could it also be this?: "Do you believe you're fighting for something, for more than your survival? Can you tell me what it is? Do you even know? Is it freedom, or truth, perhaps peace? Could it be for love? Illusions, Mr. Anderson, vagaries of perception, temporary constructs of a feeble human intellect trying desperately to justify an existence that is without meaning or purpose. And **all of them as artificial as the Matrix itself**. Although... Only a human mind can invent something as insipid as love."

Comment: @Jay - Is it possible you are remembering subtitles or dubbing in some other language that you speak, so that it could be a matter of a weird translation, or is English your only language?

Answer (score 1):

**I'm afraid you're mistaken.**

- Smith doesn't say this dialogue in any of the Matrix films
- The Wachowskis have released **no deleted scenes**/extended scenes for any of the films.
- Each of the film has received various '[alternate cuts](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0242653/alternateversions)", but only ever to *remove* footage or (very modestly) reword the dialogue for overseas audiences and **certainly not to the extent that you've mentioned**.
- Having reviewed the earlier [alternate scripts](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Matrix-Reloaded,-The.html) that have been released/leaked, **this dialogue doesn't occur in any of those either.**

Comment: this is overseas so what you said could be true. The dialog null has quoted has very complicated English words.

Comment: @Jay - I don't think they made changes as substantial as that in *any* overseas market. The most radical amendment I've read about was in the "stop bullets" speech where Neo's speech is altered to "That I can *ignore* bullets?". There were certainly no markets where they utterly rewrote the dialogue. Could you perhaps have been watching a fan-subbed copy?

Answer (score 0):

Mid way through the final fight with Neo in Revolutions, Smith comments: "It was your life that taught me the purpose of all life. The purpose of life is to end."